# After training and saving a model can we give more information as input?

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, regression, predictive-modeling

Suppose my data is a time series with multiple features such as wind, temperature, holidays, etc.. and I'm predicting a target variable Y.
After I go through the whole process of splitting data into training and test and after having good predictions/forecasts I save my model.

Can I now give extra information as input to my model? If I want to predict tomorrow's Y values and I know the wind and temperature forecasts (from weather services) for tomorrow, can't I use them to get a better prediction for tomorrow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by customizing the model with new information. But, you have to run atleast one training, with complete cycle and export output.

the general example from tensorflow is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit)

Comment: Can you provide any example/reference where something similar is being done?